# Looking for a children's book about a boy who gets arrested and taken to space

Tags: story-identification, space, childrens-novel, teleportation

The book is about a young earth boy who gets arrested by alien police. The police officer is like a wookie and has an universal translator earring. The boy has been arrested for supposedly killing a very important alien politician. He then escapes police custody and joins a space pirate crew where he learns he has the ability to teleport by seeing singularities and clapping his hands.

I can't remember what this book is called but its for my kids and I remember reading it and it being very good, any help is greatly appreciated